# git push fails for large files

Tags: git, push, git-bash

When I try to push large files in git repo, I get the following message.

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
ffatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
atal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@website.com:/X/Y/Z'
```

I use GitBash on a windows machine and the version is

```
$ git version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
```

And I have added the following to my .git/config file:

```
[pack]
    packSizeLimit = 200000000
    windowMemory = 100000000
[http]
    postBuffer = 524715200
[ssh]
    postBuffer = 524715200
```

I know you probably want to downvote this question, but I did my homework before posting this question and could not find a working solution.

Comment: If it really is a large file sometimes before the full commit is pushed the connection drops and I would guess thats the reason you have this error. Git is not designed to handle large files anyways, without knowing why you need the large file in git, rather than offering a solution to your question I would probably recommend not putting the large file in git.

Comment: @illeyezur I tried to push six files with a size of 21.8MB combined. I guess Git should be able to handle that. When I try with 100KB files, it works just fine.

Comment: 21 MB is not very large these days; "big" files that break git are in the gigabyte range now.  This probably should work.  Since you're using ssh (not http) the config entries are irrelevant (ssh does not have a "post buffer" to size here), and the problem appears to be occurring at the remote host (`website.com` above) so you may have to diagnose it from that end.

Comment: It could be a problem with the git server as well. But 21MB shouldn't be a problem for a default configurated git-daemon.

Comment: I am digging into our Git server, but meanwhile I tried to push on a linux client and was able to push 21MB files. I am thinking that the problem could have something to do with SSH configuration on GitBash on Windows...